# python beautiful soup import urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to import a list of urls and grab pn2 and main1.  I can run it without importing the file so I know it works but I just have no idea what to do with the import.  Here is what I have tried most recent and below it is a small portion of the urls.  Thanks in advance.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csvfile = open("ecco1.csv")
csvfilelist = csvfile.read()
theurl="csvfilelist"

soup = BeautifulSoup(theurl,"html.parser")
for row in csvfilelist:

    for pn in soup.findAll('td',{"class":"productText"}):
        pn2.append(pn.text)
    for main in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"breadcrumb"}):
        main1 = main.text

        print (main1)
        print ('\n'.join(pn2))
```

Urls:
    http://www.eccolink.com/products/productresults.aspx?catId=2458
    http://www.eccolink.com/products/productresults.aspx?catId=2464
    http://www.eccolink.com/products/productresults.aspx?catId=2435
    http://www.eccolink.com/products/productresults.aspx?catId=2446
    http://www.eccolink.com/products/productresults.aspx?catId=2463

Comment: what's the problem you're having? maybe you want `csvfile.readlines()`

Comment: I am not getting an error but it finishes with no results

Comment: tried csvfile.readlines() and still no results

Comment: what is `for row in csvfilelist` meant to be doing? the iterator variable `row` doesn't appear anywhere below

Comment: honestly I copied it from an answer to a similar question on this site

Comment: just removed it and still no results

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, you are opening a CSV file and using BeautifulSoup to parse it. 
That should not be the way. 
BeautifulSoup parses html files, not CSV.

Looking at your code, it seems correct if you were passing in html code to Bs4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
links = []
file = open('links.txt')
html = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for x in soup.find_all('a',"class":"abc"):
      links.append(x)
      file.write(x)
file.close()
```

Above is a very basic implementation of how I could get a target element in the html code and write it to a file/ or append it to a list. Use Requests rather than urllib. It is a better library and more modern.

If you want to input your data as CSV, my best option is to use csv reader as import.

Hope that helps.